# Merging unicode csv files python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, unicode

I have such code snippet:

```
import csv, sys, os
rootdir = sys.argv[1]
for root,subFolders, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    outfileName = rootdir + "\\root-dir.csv" # hardcoded path
    #for subdir in subFolders:
    for file in files:
        filePath = os.path.join(root, file)
        with open(filePath) as csvin:
            readfile = csv.reader(csvin, delimiter=',')
            with open(outfileName, 'a') as csvout:
                writefile = csv.writer(csvout, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
                for row in readfile:
                    row.extend([file])
                    writefile.writerow(row)
                csvout.close()
            csvin.close()
print("Ready!")
```

It works great with ascii files, but can't work with unicode versions.
Here is an example of autoruns log file: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/6Gqc/MKjKaqs8B. I need to merge some of such files into the one.
How can I change this code to do this action? It needs to be for python 2.7.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The python docs have a great example for [reading/writing to unicode CSVs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv-examples).

```
class UnicodeReader:
    """
    A CSV reader which will iterate over lines in the CSV file "f",
    which is encoded in the given encoding.
    """

    def __init__(self, f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8", **kwds):
        f = UTF8Recoder(f, encoding)
        self.reader = csv.reader(f, dialect=dialect, **kwds)

    def next(self):
        row = self.reader.next()
        return [unicode(s, "utf-8") for s in row]

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

class UnicodeWriter:
    """
    A CSV writer which will write rows to CSV file "f",
    which is encoded in the given encoding.
    """

    def __init__(self, f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8", **kwds):
        # Redirect output to a queue
        self.queue = cStringIO.StringIO()
        self.writer = csv.writer(self.queue, dialect=dialect, **kwds)
        self.stream = f
        self.encoder = codecs.getincrementalencoder(encoding)()

    def writerow(self, row):
        self.writer.writerow([s.encode("utf-8") for s in row])
        # Fetch UTF-8 output from the queue ...
        data = self.queue.getvalue()
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        # ... and reencode it into the target encoding
        data = self.encoder.encode(data)
        # write to the target stream
        self.stream.write(data)
        # empty queue
        self.queue.truncate(0)

    def writerows(self, rows):
        for row in rows:
            self.writerow(row)
```

Comment: I've tried to use it, but it didn't read data correctly. When I've tried to open an original file, it threw an error: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0. When I've deleted 2 bytes from the beginning of the file, it throws an error: line contains NULL byte

Comment: @Oleg It sounds like your datafile is UTF-16, not UTF-8.